# Chrome Dev Tools intermittently fails to show styles

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using regular Google Chrome - no extensions, latest version (auto update) and when I inspect element, sometimes it works fine, and sometimes it shows this: http://d.pr/i/huQx and ONLY this. no output of styles, etc. Closing and reopening Dev Tools temporarily fixes the problem.

Has anyone experiences this? Any recommended solution?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it happened to me as well. I uninstalled chrome, and reinstalled it and everything is working just fine now.

Comment: Sorry if that seems like the obvious answer, but it fixed mine.

Comment: Did you deleted everything Application Support/Google/Chrome? I tried that and it's still happening.

Comment: I used an uninstaller, completely cleaned it from my computer and then reinstalled it with the recommended settings.

Comment: Used AppZapper, no luck, then CCleaner, no luck. Argh. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry about that, if I come across something, I'll let you know.